# unable to Render data on handlebars to ng-tag-input field

Tags: node.js, html, express-handlebars

I trying to render the data from node server to handlebar file. but unable to access the data on ng-tag-input .
can anybody help ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more info

Comment: <tags-input ng-model="txtTags" key-property="{{TAG}}" ></tags-input> unable to acces to tag data in tag-input. i am sending data in the form of array of object e.g [{"text":"sachin"},{"text":"amit"},{"text":"abhay"}]